# What's the difference between "Krankheit", "Erkrankung" und "Erkranken"?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

I have translated *disease* into German. There are three translations for that.

I am studying the difference between them:

> Krankheit = "zeitweilige Störung der normalen Funktion eines Organismus, eines Organs, das Kranksein" ~ DWDS
>
> Erkrankung = "das Erkranken, die Krankheit" ~ DWDS
>
> Erkranken = {no entry}

My hypothesis: *Krankheit* is the general term, *Erkrankung* is chronic.

Am I right? What's the difference between them?

Comment: "Krankheit is the general term, Erkrankung is chronic" - No, not in general. Both can be an expression for a chronic illness, but both can be a non chronic illness too.

Comment: "Krankheit" and "Erkrankung" mean the same. "Krankheit" is the commonly used term, "Erkrankung" sounds more formal, it's rarely used in everyday speech. "Erkranken" is the process of getting ill, the nominal form of the verb "erkranken".

Answer (score 6):

First of all: Erkranken is the process of getting ill, not the status itself.

The other two have one common meaning where they are completely interchangeable.

This common meaning is a persons status of just being ill.

In case of *Erkrankung* in a little more specific meaning this can brake down to parts of the body being ill as in the example

> Erkrankung der Lunge

Here Krankheit can not be used.

The second meaning of *Krankheit* is the disease itself.

A flu will always be a *Krankheit* and never a *Erkrankung*.

With Erkrankung you usually describe a process / period.

Here is an example text that tries to make the difference clear:

> Joe erkrankte an der Grippe.
>   Die Krankheit schwächte seinen Körper und griff die Lunge an.
>   Die Erkrankung der Lunge schwächte ihn noch weiter.
>   Während der gesamten Dauer der Erkrankung konnte er kaum aufstehen.

Only the last *Erkrankung* could be replaced by *Krankheit* all other sentences would sound weird if you changed Krankheit and Erkrankung (though I have to admit, that in the second sentence you could use Erkrankung, but then again it would refer to his status instead of Grippe, so the meaning would change slightly).

Comment: Nice explanation. Reading so much about Erkrankung I'd rather think about "Genesung", "Genesen" and "Gesundheit" (the counterparts). :)